# Android - New to Android, is this use of Application Components is correct?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

so I'm extremely new to Android development.  The only thing that I've actually coded is Hello World.  Then I used Google App Inventor but realized that that was not what I needed.  I've also read through the developer's guide.  Anyway, I'm working on a project where we use various sensors (accelerometers by means of a wiimote and strain gauges converted to a digital signal through an Arduino microcontroller) and process the data on an Android tablet which will display the data for the user.  Then the processed data will be uploaded to a website.  Before I do anything else I need to plan out how to build this using Application Components and I wanted to make sure my general ideas are correct before I start trying to code and run into complications.  So below is a list of how I think this application should user each of the application components.

**Activities**
The user display

**Services**
Timer

**Broadcast Receivers**
Listen for new accelerometer data
Listen for new strain gauge data

**Content Providers**
Send the data to a website.

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but I find it's best to understand a tool well before I use it and I've been told that this place is noob-friendly.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> Broadcast Receivers Listen for new
>   accelerometer data Listen for new
>   strain gauge data

Not necessarily. Broadcast receivers listen for new intents. New data won't be given in an intent unless you're the one who sends it.

> Content Providers Send the data to a
>   website.

Not really. They're for inter or cross-application sharing of data, usually from a database.

It seems you don't have a very clear understanding of any of the components of Android. Instead of just guessing, you should take a look at one of the many example android projects all over the net.

Comment: OK so if you have data from an outside source, you need to issue it an intent which the broadcast receiver will hear.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense. Where are you getting the data? What outside source? Where are you reading it from? What kind of data is it? What are you doing with it?

Comment: We are getting x-y-z axis reading from accelerometers and output voltages from strain gauges.  We are using the accelerometers to detect motion and using the strain gauges to detect load.  Both are number streams. These are the outside sources I was referring to.

Comment: Yes, and how are you getting them into your app? How exactly are these sensors connected to your phone and what kind of data is coming in. "Streams" is not an answer.

Comment: The strain gauges are connected via an Arduino microcontroller, and the accelerometer data is going to be transmitted by bluetooth.

Comment: Ok the gauges are connected to the microcontroller, but that has nothing to do with Android. How are you going to get the data in android?

Comment: The idea was to connect the microcontroller to the android by USB (or bluetooth, unsure yet I need to look into Amarino more) and using Amarino to make the Arduino work on Android.

Comment: You can't get access to the usb port on android without root